# How to do aggregation with filter in django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I need to run the following SQL query in Django ORM.

`select min(time) from serverName where server_id=4912;`

I am executing the following in Django ORM.

`models.ServerName.objects.filter(server_id=ServerName.id).values(Min('time'))`

I get an error `'Min' object has no attribute 'split'`. Is there a way to have an aggregation on filter.

Comment: Dig in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the queryset's aggregate method and the models aggregation functions.

```
from django.db.models import Min
models.ServerName.objects.filter(server_id=ServerName.id).aggregate(Min('time'))
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/ for details.